# Browse IBM MQ whitout get the messages

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I'm new on IBM MQ environment so I need your help....
I need to develope a script that check an IBMMQ (outside my factory) queue to verify if there are messages waiting to be get from my application-server (I mean if my apllication-server lost the connection to IBMMQ for any reason, I want to be informed, in this mode I can take the correction).
If is possible I need the script in PowereShell or C#.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need help with the script **you're** trying to create, or do you mean you need help by us just doing the entire thing for you whilst you sit back and relax? Post your code/attempts and point out where it's going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sample code that can get you started - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/master/dotnet/dotNetGet.cs

replace the `CreateConsumer` method invocation with `CreateBrowser`

ie. the modified snippet becomes

```cs
        private void ReceiveMessagesFromEndpoint(IConnectionFactory cf)
        {
            IConnection connectionWMQ;
            ISession sessionWMQ;
            IDestination destination;
            IMessageBrowser browser;
            ITextMessage textMessage;

            // Create connection.
            connectionWMQ = cf.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection created");

            // Create session
            sessionWMQ = connectionWMQ.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            Console.WriteLine("Session created");

            // Create destination
            destination = sessionWMQ.CreateQueue(env.Conn.queue_name);
            Console.WriteLine("Destination created");

            // Create browser
            browser = sessionWMQ.CreateBrowser(destination);
            Console.WriteLine("Browser created");

            ...
```

Instructions on setup are available in the associated readme - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/master/dotnet/README.md

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No offence but that is a terrible answer.  If the queue has 100 1MB messages then browsing the queue will 100MB of unnecessary network traffic when all that is need it an integer of "100".  It is far, far better to inquire on the queue or use MQ PCF MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q command to get the current queue depth.

Comment: It's only necessary to browse a single message to know that the queue is not empty. The question wasn't asking to know how many messages are on the queue, just that there are messages on the queue. Although if it's a single large message then the network traffic argument holds.

Comment: I received from Chughts and Roger the ideas to manage my problem. I'm happy that you both understood that mine was not laziness or desire to relax .... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not browse the queue to get the current queue depth as it will cause an excessive amount of network traffic and is totally unnecessary.

Here is a C#/.NET/MQ sample program (fully functional) that will inquire on the queue for its current depth.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using IBM.WMQ;

/// <summary> Program Name
/// MQTest75
///
/// Description
/// This C# class will connect to a remote queue manager
/// and inquire on the current depth of the queue using a managed .NET environment.
///
/// </summary>
/// <author>  Roger Lacroix
/// </author>
namespace MQTest75
{
   class MQTest75
   {
      private Hashtable qMgrProp = null;
      private System.String qManager;
      private System.String inputQName;

      /*
      * The constructor
      */
      public MQTest75()
         : base()
      {
      }

      /// <summary> Make sure the required parameters are present.</summary>
      /// <returns> true/false
      /// </returns>
      private bool allParamsPresent()
      {
         bool b = false;

         if ( (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QMgrName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"] != null) )
         {
            try
            {
               System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
               b = true;
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               b = false;
            }
         }

         return b;
      }

      /// <summary> Extract the configuration applicaiton settings and initialize the MQ variables.</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      /// <throws>  IllegalArgumentException </throws>
      private void init(System.String[] args)
      {
         if (allParamsPresent())
         {
            qManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QMgrName"];
            inputQName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];

            qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"]);
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelName"]);

            try
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]));
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
            }

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"]);

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

            logger("Parameters:");
            logger("  QMgrName ='" + qManager + "'");
            logger("  Queue Name ='" + inputQName + "'");

            logger("Connection values:");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in qMgrProp)
            {
               logger("  " + de.Key + " = '" + de.Value + "'");
            }
         }
         else
         {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Connect, open queue, output the current queue depth, close queue and disconnect.</summary>
      /// <throws>  MQException </throws>
      private void handleIt()
      {
         MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
         MQQueue inQ = null;
         int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

         try
         {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, qMgrProp);
            logger("Successfully connected to " + qManager);

            inQ = qMgr.AccessQueue(inputQName, openOptions);
            logger("Successfully opened " + inputQName);

            logger("Current queue depth is " + inQ.CurrentDepth);
         }
         catch (MQException mqex)
         {
            logger("CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
         {
            logger("Error: ioex=" + ioex);
         }
         finally
         {
            try
            {
                if (inQ != null)
                {
                    inQ.Close();
                    logger("Closed: " + inputQName);
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                logger("CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }

            try
            {
                if (qMgr != null)
                {
                    qMgr.Disconnect();
                    logger("Disconnected from " + qManager);
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                logger("CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Output the log message to stdio.</summary>
      /// <param name="data">
      /// </param>
      private void logger(String data)
      {
         DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
         System.Console.Out.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + this.GetType().Name + ": " + data);
      }

      /// <summary> main line</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      //        [STAThread]
      public static void Main(System.String[] args)
      {
         MQTest75 mqt = new MQTest75();

         try
         {
            mqt.init(args);
            mqt.handleIt();
         }
         catch (System.ArgumentException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Check your configuration file for an incorrect parameter.");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }

         System.Environment.Exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Just create a configuration called ***MQTest75.exe.config*** and put the following in it:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="QMgrName" value="MQA1"/>
    <add key="ConnectionName" value="10.10.10.10"/>
    <add key="Port" value="1414"/>
    <add key="ChannelName" value="TEST.CHL"/>
    <add key="QueueName" value="TEST.Q1"/>
    <add key="UserId" value="tester"/>
    <add key="Password" value="mypwd"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```